# google map geocoding api webservice return address type changes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

We noticed the google map geocoding api now returns different address types. For addresses used to be "street_address" in the "type" XML element, some could be "premise" instead. We are filtering the response based on the data value in the "type" XML elements in the response.

Besides "premise" and "street_address", is there any other value could be in the "type" XML element that would result in as a match to street level?  What values have been added to it since Feb. 14th, 2017 in the Release version: 3.27?  Where can I find the exact changes on the revisions related to google map geocoding api?

Comment: why down vote? do you have an answer to these questions?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change that you observe is not related to version 3.27 of Maps JavaScript API. Google has announced a [new version of forward geocoder](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html) back in November 2016.

This version of geocoder can find more things than previous version could. For example POIs and businesses can be found as well.

Have a look at this example:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3Daaa%26nfw%3D1

You can see the following types: "car_repair, establishment, insurance_agency, point_of_interest, travel_agency"

The changes also are described in the following documents:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/faq

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters, here's a list of all the currently supported values for the `type` field: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types

Comment: I did read about the Types in the documentation prior to asking the question.  It is not clear to me the exact changes for the address lookup in the google map geocoding api web service in the release 3.27, as it broke our applications at this monment.